# What is SOAP Endpoint while connecting SFMC using Mulesoft?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, mulesoft, client-id

What is SOAP Endpoint while connecting SFMC using Mulesoft?
Whether endpoint is generic or for email we need some other endpoint?
[image: SOAP Endpoint?????]

Answer (score 4):

These depend on what stack you are on.

you can check what stack your are on by:

- Going to trust.marketingcloud.com and entering your MID number
- log into marketing cloud and check the prefix to the url. It would be s*something* eg **s7.mc.exacttarget.com** would mean you are on the s7 stack

> ### Endpoint Links

---

> **Stack           WSDL Link**
>
> S1 Instance     https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
>
> S4 Instance       https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
>
> S6 Instance       https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
>
> S7 Instance       https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
>
> S10 Instance    https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
>
> Sandbox Instance  https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

Reference:

- [Getting started with SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm)